# Add to current string using javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, str-replace

I would like to add to the current string using javascript. Currently, It is working fine but I am doing it in a very dirty way currently. I am basically replacing the WHOLE string instead of just adding to it. Is there a way that I can just add a comma and continue my string?

JS:

```
var mystring = "'bootstrap'"
console.log(mystring.replace(/bootstrap/g , "'bootstrap', 'bootstrap2', 'bootstrap3'"));
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nx956b2u/)**

Comment: Personally I don't see anything wrong with that. A "replace" is supposed to replace one thing with another, even if that other thing is similar to the first thing. Only thing I see weird here is you end up with too many single-quotes in your result.

Comment: In my comment, I'm assuming that your original string is longer than it's showing in your example, with your value in the middle, like `someText, 'bootstrap', someOtherText`. If that's not the case, and you actually are just adding on to the end of a string, then I agree with the answers that are coming in, that you can simply append to the string.

Comment: without repeating 'bootstrap' , but ignoring order,  you can replace with lookahead regex

Comment: like this :/ `mystring.replace(/^(?='(bootstrap)')/, '\'$12\', ')`

Answer (score 2):

You can add to the end of a string by using the `+=`operator. [See the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators) regarding string operators.

```js
var mystring = "'bootstrap'"
mystring += ", 'bootstrap2'";
mystring += ", 'bootstrap3'";
console.log(mystring);
```

Comment: My issue is that I am getting content from a file which is why I was originally using replace

Comment: You'll need to add additional explanation in the question regarding the format of the content you are retrieving from file if you do not think this answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can concat strings with the [`+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_()):

```js
var mystring = "'bootstrap'" + ",";
console.log(mystring);
```

Comment: My issue is that I am getting content from a file which is why I was originally using replace

Comment: @user4756836, what do you mean you are getting the content from a file? Either way, you should still have the content in a variable. You may want to update your answer to show what you start with, and what you are expecting as the end result.

Answer (score 2):

> You can concatenate( `+` operator ) instead of replace if you just want the second string to get appended to the first string.

```js
var mystring = "'bootstrap'"
var newString = mystring +", "+ "'bootstrap', 'bootstrap2', 'bootstrap3'";
console.log( newString );
```

Comment: My issue is that I am getting content from a file which is why I was originally using replace

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
mystring += "'bootstrap2',";
```

or

```
var arr = ["str1", "str2", "str3"];
var mystring = arr.map((e)=>{return "'"+e+"'";}).join(",")
```

Array.map function used to wrap each string with single quates, than you Array.join - used to put "," between members

Comment: My issue is that I am getting content from a file which is why I was originally using replace

Answer (score 1):

Use an array and the join method.

```js
var arr = [];
var myString = "bootstrap";

arr.push(myString);
arr.push(myString);
arr.push("other string");
arr.push("bootstrap");

// combine them with a comma or something else
console.log(arr.join(', '));
```

Comment: My issue is that I am getting content from a file which is why I was originally using replace

Answer (score 0):

It is **not suggested**, but if you want to keep symbols and not care about order, and want to only add to a string beginning with `'bootstrap'`:

```js
myString = "'bootstrap'";
console.log(myString.replace(/^(?='(bootstrap)')/, "'$12', '$13', "));
```

or you can just use capture group to keep it short

```
mystring.replace(/'(bootstrap)'/, "'$1', '$12', '$13'")
```